# Date format not recognized while returning results

Tags: oracle, hp-ux

```
select * from table where trunc(value1)=to_date('25-AUG-15','DD-MON-YY');
```

This is  fine

```
select * from table where trunc(value1)=to_date('25-AUG-15','DD-Mon-YY');
```

This returned as well although the valid value should be 25-Aug-15

Even this works,

```
select * from table where trunc(value1)=to_date('25/AUG/15','DD-MON-YY');
```

result is returned

And this,

```
 select * from table where trunc(value1) = to_date('25-AUG-15', 'DD-MM-YY');
```

result is returned

but this works very well

```
 select * from table where trunc(value1) = to_date('25-AUG-15','MMDDYY');
```

it checks for the month, which is not found and returns error(well parsed!!!)

Why is that format specifier is not performing strict check on the date value supplied?

Thanks.

Comment: The first two queries are identical. The format mask is case **in**sensitive. `DD-MON-YY` is the exactly the same as `dd-mon-yy`. The last one however is strange.

Comment: what oracle version you are using

Comment: it would seem that `TO_DATE` ignores characters in the input string and mask that it doesn't care about. Try `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) = TO_DATE('17SEP15','DD!MON@YY')`

Comment: ----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.5.0      Production
TNS for HPUX: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production

Comment: So if this means that it's case sensitive , ignores the characters in between other than date,month,year and sometimes even string or number diff like DD-MON-YY and DD-MM-YY both return results, only the placing of date, month,year matters

Comment: I've never seen `MON` and `MM` treated like that!

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has said, why are you specifying your date with 2-digit years? Surely in this post-y2k era it's the norm to use all 4 digits? Why take the risk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be Oracle trying to do you a solid and make it easy to parse dates into something sensible. I can't find any documentation to support this, but not only is the format mask case insensitive, but it would appear that any sequence of non-alphanumeric characters that are not a control characters that appear in either the input string or the format mask are *treated as required wildcards*, such that from Oracle's perspective:

```
TO_DATE('17!!!SEP£££15', 'DD$$$MON***YY')
```

is identical to:

```
TO_DATE('170915', 'DDMONYY')
```

If the number and position of the wildcards in your input don't match those of the format mask, you'll get a exception relating to the next token it is looking for:

```
TO_DATE('17!!!!SEP-15', 'DD-MON-YY')

ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

However, it gets even more weird when you look at how the wildcards in the format mask are interpreted. It seems that between tokens, any sequence of non-alphanumeric characters is treated as a single *but optional* wildcard, such that:

```
TO_DATE('17-SEP-15','DD----------------MON-YY')
```

is the same as:

```
TO_DATE('17-SEP-15','DD-MON-YY')
```

and because the wildcards in the format mask are option, also has the same effect as:

```
 TO_DATE('17-SEP-15','DD-MON-YY')
```

Comment: In addition to this, there is "fx", which means the string must exactly match the format model. See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216

Comment: I think I have found my answer:  select 1 from dual where trunc(sysdate) = TO_DATE('17/SEP/15', 'FXDD-MON-YY'); ( returns error)  as well as this select 1 from dual where trunc(sysdate) = TO_DATE('17-SEP-15','FXDD-MM-YY');

Comment: Thanks Boneist for the fx information, heard this for the first time